# How can implement AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer for java config on my spring 3.2 and hibernate 4 integration project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

On my application, I am using spring 3.2, jsf 2.1 and hibernate 4 integration. I want to replace configuration xml files to java config. For that I am focusing on AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter section.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name />
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
   /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
   </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <description>generated-persistence-filter</description>
    <filter-name>MySQLFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>MySQL</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MySQLFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>   
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/jsf/login.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

how can implement context-param , welcome-file-list  and  error-page on javaconfig class.

My javaconfig class is,

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/", "/*", "*.faces", "*.xhtml" };
}

@Override  // for representing Faces Serelet context, is it correct?
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
    servletContext.addServlet("Faces Servlet", "javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet");


    super.onStartup(servletContext);
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter openEntityManagerInViewFilter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
    openEntityManagerInViewFilter.setPersistenceUnitName("MySQL");
    return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter, openEntityManagerInViewFilter, new org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter()};
}
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(DatabaseConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.shiv.ShivCDB.web.jsf", "com.shiv.ShivCDB.service" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
}

@Bean
public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
    SimpleMappingExceptionResolver b = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

    Properties mappings = new Properties();
    mappings.put("org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound", "p404");
    mappings.put("org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException", "dataAccessFailure");
    mappings.put("org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException", "dataAccessFailure");
    b.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
    return b;
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {

    CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(StringUtils.parseLocaleString("en"));
    return cookieLocaleResolver;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages/messages", "classpath:messages/validation");
    // if true, the key of the message will be displayed if the key is not
    // found, instead of throwing a NoSuchMessageException
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    // # -1 : never reload, 0 always reload
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    return messageSource;
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like a spring and hibernate problem non-related with JSF. Note that JSF here will act as a mere HTML generator only.

Comment: how can implement properties like context-param, welcome-file-list and error-page (web.xml) on spring 3.2 java configuration class.

Answer (score 3):

you need to register spring ContextLoaderListener in your **onStartup** method, for xml configuration:

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
    XmlWebApplicationContext root = new XmlWebApplicationContext
    root.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root))
}
```

for java config:

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
//scan the package of your @Configuration java files
    root.scan("org.example.config")
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root))
}
```

It looks like there is no annotations or java config support for welcome-file list and error-pages, you still have to define them in web.xml and servlet container will load both web.xml and WebInitializer.

If you want to entirely get rid of web.xml, you can try to implement welcome file and error page in your web framework.

--edit--

I am not familiar with jsf, you can try to add following in method **onStartup** :

```
servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD", "server");
servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.expressionFactory", "com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl");
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am doing to implement error page and welcome file on framework level. But yet exist <context-param>    like javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD and com.sun.faces.expressionFactory on web.xml. How can implement that on WebInitializer java config